# jQuery resizing won't work inside iframe, it only tracks the mouse outside the iframe instead of inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-ui-resizable

I have an iframe with an image inside it. 
I need to allow the user to resize the image by clicking on it and dragging from the corners. 
 I've been using the jquery ui resizable functionality partially successfully. Currently it will allow the drag and stretch resizing...but only when the mouse is outside the iframe. I need to opposite to be the case, where it follows the mouse for the drag/stretch only when it's in the iframe.

Any idea on how i can achieve that?

Comment: you would need your javascript to be in the iframe itself. As far as I know javascript on a page can not manipulate what is in an iframe. I think is is a browser security thing. Is there any particular reason the image is in an iframe?

Comment: if you need a script to auto-resize the iframe size, use these 2 scripts. 1 in the parent, 1 in the child(iframe) for automatic adjustment of the iframe https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: The javascript is also in the iframe.

Comment: The image is in the iframe because the iframe is where the content from the wysiwyg goes. The user puts their content (images, links, text, etc) there and they need to be able to resize that image.

Comment: @zer02, it is the image inside the iframe, rather than the iframe itself that needs to be resized.

Comment: there is a draggable option in jQuery UI iframeFix:true, maybe it helps http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-iframeFix

Comment: @zer02 thanks, i've tried it ... no luck